# Can't add second OR to the Criteria

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm trying to add a second OR to my Criteria. 
I'm getting an error that 
`Due to limitations of the com.mongodb.BasicDBObject, you can't add a second 'null' criteria`

When I debugged it I saw that the first OR is adding to the HashMap of Criteria a value with null as a key. 
The moment it trying to add the second one, it finds that the null key exists so it throws an error.

```
    if (par1 != null) {
        query.addCriteria(
                new Criteria().orOperator(
                        Criteria.where(Book.SOME_FIELD + "." + BookDetail.CATEGORY_FIELD).is(par1),
                        Criteria.where(Book.OTHER_FIELD + "." + BookDetail.CATEGORY_FIELD).is(par1)
                )

        );

    }

    if (par2 != null) {

        query.addCriteria(
                new Criteria().orOperator(
                        Criteria.where(Book.SOME_FIELD + "." + BookDetail.TYPE_FIELD).is(par2),
                        Criteria.where(Book.OTHER_FIELD + "." + BookDetail.TYPE_FIELD).is(par2)
                )

        );
    }
```

I want to check the non-null parameters with the corresponding fields.

it's working if I'm sending only 1 parameter. 
The problem is when I'm sending 2 parameters at the same time.

Thanks.

Comment: you need to link the two OR statements... select x from y where (a=1 or b=1) or (a=2 or b=2) - you can also add all statements to one or (where a1=1 or b=1 or a=2 or b=2) - then you need to add all in one

Answer (score 0):

In case both parameters are not null you have to combine this into one single criteria with andOperator() instead of calling two separate addCriteria methods, something like this:

```
    if(par1 != null && par2 != null){
          query.addCriteria(
            new Criteria().andOperator(
              new Criteria().orOperator(
                Criteria.where(Book.SOME_FIELD + "." + BookDetail.CATEGORY_FIELD).is(par1),
                Criteria.where(Book.OTHER_FIELD + "." + BookDetail.CATEGORY_FIELD).is(par1)),
              new Criteria().orOperator(
                Criteria.where(Book.SOME_FIELD + "." + BookDetail.TYPE_FIELD).is(par2),
                Criteria.where(Book.OTHER_FIELD + "." + BookDetail.TYPE_FIELD).is(par2)));
    } else if (par1 != null) {
          query.addCriteria(
            new Criteria().orOperator(
              Criteria.where(Book.SOME_FIELD + "." + BookDetail.CATEGORY_FIELD).is(par1),
              Criteria.where(Book.OTHER_FIELD + "." + BookDetail.CATEGORY_FIELD).is(par1)));
    } else if (par2 != null) {
          query.addCriteria(
            new Criteria().orOperator(
              Criteria.where(Book.SOME_FIELD + "." + BookDetail.TYPE_FIELD).is(par2),
              Criteria.where(Book.OTHER_FIELD + "." + BookDetail.TYPE_FIELD).is(par2)));
    }
```